# Warning: sqlite_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, sql, html, database, sqlite

I've looked all over the place and cant find a solution that helps my case. I hope someone can help?

I have this and receive

> Warning: sqlite_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

It is relating to `$dbresult` line - so a problem with the query.

```
function Up(){ 
$dbquery = "DELETE FROM toolList WHERE toolId='".$data['toolId']."'";  
$dbresult = sqlite_query($dbhandle, $dbquery);  
}
     
foreach($result as $data){ 
 print '< a href="'.Up().'">DELETE!< /a>';  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `$dbhandle` defined? I'm guessing it's a global variable, in which case you have to explicitly mention so within the `Up` function:

```
function Up(){ 
  global $dbhandle, $data, $dbresult;
  $dbquery = "DELETE FROM toolList WHERE toolId='".$data['toolId']."'";  
  $dbresult = sqlite_query($dbhandle, $dbquery);  
}
```

Comment: great!! thanks, that gets rid of the warning, but doesnt seem to work still!

Comment: it should grab $data from the foreach loop right?

Comment: You probably want to pass `$data` as a parameter to `Up`.

Answer (score 1):

You are either missing a call to [sqlite_open()](http://php.net/sqlite_open), or your `$dbhandle` variable is not available in your function.